# Scapy: Update field after building with post_build function

Tags: python, layer, packet, scapy

I'm trying to build an own layer in Scapy which contains a "LengthField". This field should contain the total size of this layer + everything that follows.
I know that the "post_build" method is what I need to achieve this and I have tried to understand how it is used in the Scapy Documentation, but I do not understand it.

Let's say I have a layer

```
class MyLayer(Packet):

    name = "MyLayer"
    fields_desc = [
                   ByteField("SomeField", 1),
                   IntField("LengthField", 0)
                   ]
```

How do I need to modify this class so it can automatically update the LengthField upon buildung?

Answer (score 3):

```
def post_build(self, p, pay):
    p += pay
    if self.LengthField is None:
        p = p[:1] + struct.pack("I", len(p)) + p[5:]
        hexdump(p)
    return p
```

You can refer to some examples in the source code:

```
class HCI_Command_Hdr(Packet):
    name = "HCI Command header"
    fields_desc = [XLEShortField("opcode", 0),
                   ByteField("len", None), ]

    def post_build(self, p, pay):
        p += pay
        if self.len is None:
            p = p[:2] + struct.pack("B", len(pay)) + p[3:]
        return p
```

The result is:

```
>>> (HCI_Command_Hdr()/"1234567").show2()
###[ HCI Command header ]### 
  opcode= 0x0
  len= 7
###[ Raw ]### 
     load= '1234567'
```

You can print `p` and `pay` to understand the code:

```
 p[:2] + struct.pack("B", len(pay)) + p[3:]
```

Then, modify it to achieve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

fix the fields size with the length of a new `MyLayer` in `post_dissect`. Note that you cannot use `len(str(self))` for length calculation as you'll end up in an endless recursion due to `str()` calling `do_dissect`.

```
class MyLayer(Packet):
    name = "MyLayer"
    fields_desc = [
                   ByteField("SomeField", 1),
                   LenField("LengthField", None),   # calcs len(pkt.payload)
                   ]
    def post_dissect(self, s):
        self.LengthField += len(str(self.__class__()))     # add this layer size by creating a new temporary layer and calculating its size.
        return Packet.post_dissect(self, s)
```

the value will be calculated upon `show2()`

```
(MyLayer()/Raw().show2()
```

results in

```
###[ MyLayer ]###
  SomeField = 1
  LengthField= 9
###[ Raw ]###
     load      = 'hihiii'
```

where 9 = 6 bytes payload (Raw) + 1 byte (SomeField) + 2 Bytes (LenField with fmt="H" == shortInt == 2bytes)

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution using `post_build()`, too, in which the length is then added on binary level, but this solution seems better.

Comment: No, post_dissect is for dissection (when getting a packet), not when building it